# How to reset power settings on Windows 11?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, temperature

On my company Lenovo L13 (i5-1145G7 2.60GHz, 16GB), the fan never stops, even when CPU temperature is just at 41C.

It's been MONTHS of non-stop fan, nobody knows what is going on, I am getting mad.

- Cooling works mostly as expected: when temperature gets higher, the fan speed is also higher, I can see the temperature increase and decrease, and when temperature decreases fan slows down, but it never stops, even at temperatures as low as 41C
- When the temperature goes so low, of course, there are no background tasks or antivirus or anything keeping the CPU at high frequency
- The fan temporarily stops when starting the laptop and before Windows boots up
- After Windows starts, it never stops again
- Windows 10 would stop the fan after certain temperature threshold
- I have tried selecting Balanced and Best power efficiency settings on Windows
- I have tried manually setting a low CPU frequency on power settings from the old control panel (has an option so select the % of max CPU frequency)
- The CPU is actually working at a lower speed (right now 1104)
- As a company laptop I can't install software to manage the fan
- I can't boot on a live linux USB, it's locked

How I am checking temperature:

```
(Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ThermalZoneInformation" -Namespace "root/CIMV2").HighPrecisionTemperature/10-273.15
```

Clock speed:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Property CurrentClockSpeed
```

Processes:

```
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 1} | Sort-Object -Descending -Property CookedValue | Select -Property InstanceName,CookedValue
```

Question: is there any way to check what process/driver is actually in charge of the fan? How can it be reset? Is it possible to manually check/reset the temperature threshold?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the system firmware? (And the embedded controller if the laptop has one?) We just had to do that for a pair of Lenovo desktops; wouldn't stay quiet until we did the whole "clear CMOS/NVRAM" process.

Comment: No, haven't tried that. Is it safe? Does it affect TPM/Bitlocker keys?

Comment: It can affect TPM contents, so yeah, have your BitLocker recovery key at hand. (I assume the company would have also set up all machines to store their recovery keys centrally.) Other than that, it should be safe; it clears any firmware settings but on a modern laptop they're all sensible by default, and it doesn't erase the firmware itself or anything like that. Check with IT team to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with IT to perform it. I'll update if it fixes it :)

Comment: [Fan Control](https://github.com/Rem0o/FanControl.Releases/releases/tag/V181) may help and can be used without installation when downloaded as a Zip. You probably would need release `FanControl_net_4_8.zip`. But better verify if your IT people agree to it. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Thank you, I will suggest that too!

Comment: I've been looking online for the procedure of resetting the L13 NVRAM/CMOS without any luck, even at the Lenovo site. Is resetting the NVRAM/CMOS the same as the "Emergency reset" button?

Comment: @georgh: It *might* be if you hold it long enough (try 60+ seconds)? Other than that, the instructions for [removing the power-on password](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/l13_gen3_l13yoga_gen3_hmm_en.pdf#page=35) might clear the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

> On my **company** Lenovo L13 (i5-1145G7 2.60GHz, 16GB), the fan never stops, even when CPU temperature is just at 41C.

Usually these are under contract so your company needs to get a Lenovo tech to assess it.

If not then an IT guy needs to assess.

> It's been MONTHS of non-stop fan, **nobody** knows what is going on, I am getting mad.

Who are all these "nobody"s? Did you ask the right somebody?

> As a company laptop I can't install software to manage the fan

It sounds like you've done all that you can do, now you need to pester the right person.

Honestly, you've done too much. Your demeanor should have been "Hey, this thing sounds like it's gonna blow up, can you look at it? Thanks."

---

The right person needs to assess your machine.

Possible solutions include:

- Check BIOS settings for a fan curve
- Update firmware
- Update the BIOS
- Re-install Windows

Comment: I had checked with the company service desk and after having the ticket open since December without anything useful, I've tried to get more information.
In another comment it has been suggested to do an NVRAM reset, so I will be asking IT about this.

Comment: @georgh Stop trying to do IT's job for them. Complain to your boss; they should have a chain to get a knowledgeable person's eyes on the issue.

Comment: problem is the day I'm at the office is when antivirus runs all day, so it doesn't help as they always say "it's because of the AV", which is true, except when it's not :/